# Invert a singular matrix (Laplacian to inverse Laplacian)

Tags: matlab, matrix, fortran, octave, lapack

I am porting a 2d CFD code written in Octave/Matlab to fortran. The domain is periodic, so the scheme is based on FT. The following matrix, 'laplacian':

> 0   -1   -4   -9   -4   -1
>
> -1   -2   -5  -10   -5   -2
>
> -4   -5   -8  -13   -8   -5
>
> -9  -10  -13  -18  -13  -10
>
> -4   -5   -8  -13   -8   -5
>
> -1   -2   -5  -10   -5   -2

represents the Laplacian operator for a FT on a 6 by 6 grid.  I want the inverse matrix, even though Laplacian is singular.  In matlab/octave, 'inv(laplacian)' returns all 'Inf', however '1./laplacian' returns the correct answer (albeit the (1,1) element, returned as Inf, has to be set to zero).

The question is how to translate the second form using LAPACK.  My usual matrix inversion sequence 'DGETRF/DGETRI' fails with info=4, no surprise.  There are some twenty other DxxTRF. Does anyone know what might stand a chance of doing what Octave does?

Comment: You rarely want to invert a matrix in scientific computing. Even when you manage to get the matrix inversion, it is slower to use after it is computed  than using an LU decomposition. In the end you want to solve a linear system, don't you? You don't need a matrix inversion for that.

Comment: I concur with Vladimir.  Not only are inverse unnecessary, they tend to be numerically unstable -- small changes in the original matrix can produce large changes in the inverse, so rounding errors are amplified.  And L-U decomposition is a much better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing what I think you are then you want to multiply different wavenumbers of the Fourier transform by different coefficients which are derived from the eigenvalues of the Laplacian operator.

Something like

```
lambda(kx, ky, kz) = (kx**2 + ky**2 + kz**2)
```

Notice the 1, 4, and 9 in your "matrix". They are these squares `kx**2`.

That is NOT a matrix inversion, that is really just dividing 1.0 by numbers which are written in a form of a table. The table looks like a matrix, because your code is 2D, so you have just `lambda(kx, ky)`.

The whole actual matrix for the Laplacian operator would be very big (N times N, where N=`nx*ny` in 2D and N=`nx*ny*nz` in 3D) and would have the `lambda`s on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else. The inverse matrix would have `1./labda`s on the diagonal. So your operation is matrix inversion in a sense, but in a different sense than you thought.

What you than do is

```
FT(kx,ky,kz) = FT(kx,ky,kz) / (kx**2 + ky**2 + kz**2)
```

which can be also written as

```
FT = FT * inv_laplacian
```

where

```
inv_laplacian = 1. / laplacian
```

where `laplacian` is the coefficient (eigenvalue) array.

That is NOT a matrix inversion, it is just dividing 1.0 by numbers.

---

Now, what the do with the 0 eigenvalue? If you do not enable floating point exception trapping, and I advice you against enabling them, then you just do:

```
 FT = FT * inv_laplacian
```

Because `inv_laplacian(0,0,0)` is 0,  FT(0,0,0) was divided by 0 and is undefined (NaN or similar). You can just set it to whatever you want. The meaning of `FT(0,0,0)` is the mean value of your field, which is arbitrary. So do just

```
 FT(0,0,0) = 0 !or any number you want
```

and that's it.

---

BTW I have seen even extreme practices in a real world scientific code such as:

```
for i =0, nkx-1
  for j =0, nkx-1
    for k =0, nkx-1
      FT(i, j, k) = FT(i, j, k) / (cos(i*ax) + cos(j*ay) + cos(k*az)
    end 
  end
end
```

it took AGES to compute. It is very similar to your case, your eigenvalues are just  not cosines but squares.

The point is that the coefficients are CONSTANT in time and SEPARABLE.

One can just compute once:

```
lambdax(i) = i**2 !or cos(ax*i)
lambday(i) = j**2 !or cos(ay*j)
lambdaz(i) = k**2 !or cos(az*k)
```

and then do

```
FT(kx,ky,kz) = FT(kx,ky,kz) / (lambdax(kx) + lambday(ky) + lambdaz(kz))
```

---

You can have a look at the source code of my fast Poisson solver PoisFFT to see an example https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/poisfft-solvers-inc.f90 and find the appropriate boundary conditions. Your case is likely PoisFFT_Solver2D_FullPeriodic on line 152.

Comment: @VladimirF Awesome answer, I have marked it as answer since I know it will take me time to work through all you have written. In response to your fist short comment, since the laplacian is constant, I thought it would be faster to get 1/laplaciam once and for all.  I suppose your point is that multiplying 1/laplacian by some array is no faster than solving the linear system??

Comment: The numbers in `inv_laplacian` are actually the eigenvalues of the inverse Laplace operator. But it is not a matrix. They are eigenvalues for different wavenumbers.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks again

Comment: I might have been confusing. It is a collection of eigenvalues of the inverse matrix. Someone could call it a sparse matrix representation of the inverse matrix, but it is not the actual matrix itself. The only reason why you can use an inverse matrix here is because it is diagonal. In general we don't want to use sparse matrices, they are usually dense and slow to use.